# No backends were found

Tags: cucumber-java

I am trying to run runner class in Intelli J idea but getting this error message

cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: No backends were found. Please make sure you have a backend module on your CLASSPATH.

I spend lots of time but I don't know how this will work?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the reason for this is that you are using several cucumber dependencies with different versions.

Make sure that **all your cucumber dependencies** are using the **same version** number. You can find which dependencies you need in the [installation docs](https://cucumber.io/docs/installation/java/)

Comment: Yw. If above it the correct answer, could you accept it please?